can I say ' Baz has just seen a wreck and. he was swimming towards it '?
Is it correct to use present perfect 'yet or just' with past continuous in the same sentence??
Or I have to use present continuous??
' Baz has just seen a wreck he is swimming towards it' ??

Without context it looks wrong. It is unclear what you are trying to say, or how these events are ordered in time.
In context it might be possible.  This isn't a grammar error, so you just need something to understand how things are related in time. But if he has "just" seen the wreck (ie very recently) then there isn't any time between then and now for him to be swimming.  This makes it incongruent.
For a learner, it is unlikely that this combination of tenses would be used in any natural situation, and so it should be avoided.

I would suggest "Baz has just seen a wreck and [has just] started to swim towards it." (You would leave out the words in square brackets, as they can be understood from the context.)

How about "Baz ?has just seen a wreck and was now swimming towards it" - with the sequence of events being obvious from adverbs of time? Past Perfect would still be preferable, I think, but it doesn't feel as unnatural as OP's example.
